# QuickDialog: How to create a field for long, multiline text?

Tags: ios, iphone, quickdialog

I am using QuickDialog to create a form in my iOS app. For one of the items that I am asking users about, I would prefer a multi-line text field as it's an open-ended question (e.g., do you have any questions?). `QEntryElement` only has a single line, and the space to type is pretty small on an iPhone. Any suggestions for how to do a larger text entry space using QuickDialog?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `QEntryElement`, use `QMultilineElement`. It works exactly the same way - the only problem being that `QMultilineElement` does not display what the user entered on the main form screen.